# Input (submit) element occupies extra space in Firefox

Tags: html, css

A web page with a link, an input (submit) and a span. All are styled to have the same look, actually the input is styled to have the same look as the hyperlink and span.

[image]

Tested using: Firefox 3.0, 3.6, 4.0, 14.0.1

For some reason, the input is slightly bigger among the others. Also, the text of the input is not aligned with text of link and span. Here's a live demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/LGftW/

Here's my CSS:

```
a{
    text-decoration:none;
}

input[type="submit"]{
    border:0 none;
    background:transparent;
}

a, input[type="submit"], span{
    border:solid 1px green;
    font-size:64px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Markup:

```
<a href="#">LINK</a>
<input type="submit" value="INPUT" />
<span>SPAN</span>
```

So how can I make an input to look like an ordinary link or span? Is it weird a behavior of browser or I just missed some CSS? I've been solving this for a day now.

**Edit**

It seems like the problem occurs only in Firefox. IE8-9 and Chrome display it correctly.

Comment: It's just because of the `font-size`

Comment: @Mr.Alien I used firebug and it says all of them have font size of 64px. Also, it's in my CSS, didn't you see it?

Comment: @dpp The fiddle seems to be all right , don't you think so , it is different from the image you provided.

Comment: @freebird what browser are you using?

Comment: @freebird Aha! The problem only occurs in Firefox. IE8-9 and chrome works fine.

Comment: and the problem is still unsolved...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove button padding in Firefox by using `input::-moz-focus-inner` in your CSS:

```
input::-moz-focus-inner /*Remove button padding in FF*/ 
{
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**EDITED: Updated Demo Link with above code.**

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RuBQY/) in firefox

Comment: Nope! the height is still not matched

Comment: @Dipaks: It's working fine on my side. I am using Firefox14.0.1.

Comment: I am using the same.. Did you notice the green border? It's different

Comment: @A.K You did not apply the style on fiddle, when it's added everything works fine.

Comment: replaced the fiddle-link with one that includes A.K. change: http://jsfiddle.net/LGftW/15/